# File upload field with custom validation in yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

The usual way to upload a file in yesod is using `fileAFormOpt`/`fileAFormReq`. However, these don't result in a `Field` value, but go straight to an AForm, which is why I can't simply use the `check` function in `Yesod.Form.Functions`.

How would I add custom validation for Yesod file upload?

(My use case is that I want to check if the `fileContentType` of the uploaded file is in a specific list of valid types.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think this is a weakness in the current API. The only way I can think of to implement this would be to basically copy-paste the existing function and make your change. Clearly this is not acceptable.

Could you email the mailing list about this so we can try and design a better API?